# Incrementing an ID using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-web-api, lambda

Whenever I'm adding a new object from the front end, the id = 0.  In the WebApi layer, I'm trying to find the max ID that exists in the list of object and then assign the next ID to the new objects.  The code below doesn't increment the ID correctly

```
List<Event> events = eventVal.Where(e => e != null).ToList();
int eventMaxID = events.Max(e => e.id);

events.Where(e => e.id == 0)
  .Select((e, ixc) => new { id = eventMaxID + 1, Iter = eventMaxID + 1 })
  .ToList();
```

I'm not sure how to use the second parameter for the Select method.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Is your example code correct? Your call to `events.Select(e => e.id == 0)` looks like you mean `events.Where(e => e.id == 0)`

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second form of Select that you're using, ixc is the index of the item in the collection. You'll need to add that as well as the previous max Id. That way you shouldn't have to worry about assigning to Iter either (it appears you're just using it as some kind of counter) so I've removed it.

```
var autoIncrementedEvents = events.Where(e => e.id == 0)
  .Select((e, ixc) => 
  {
     e.id = eventMaxId + 1 + ixc;
     return e;
  })
  .ToList();
```

Note that the way your code is written the result of this Linq statment is thrown away. You'll want to assign it to something like I've done above.

I'm not going to comment on the validity of this as an overall approach in a web setting (race conditions, duplicate ids, etc). Ideally your datastore should be assigning the Id.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "didn't work". It's hard to tell exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: That didn't work.  I'm trying to update the ID column in the event to the next incremented ID. `List<Event> newEvent = events.Where(e => e.id == 0)
                                      .Select((e, ixc) => new { id = ixc + eventMaxID + 1 + e.id})
                                      .ToList();` Gives the error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<anonymous type: int id> to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<events.api.Models.Event>

Comment: @rds80 Linq is for selecting and transforming. You have now transformed the `Event` to an anonymous type.

Comment: @rds80 That's because you were using new {} which creates an anonymous object. I was simply copying from your original question. If you need to deal with an Event see my updated code snippet

Comment: @JesseCarter the first Select is actually a Where, see the comments in the question and my update

Comment: Thanks @JesseCarter, that worked! So do you recommend this to be done on the ORM or database side?

Comment: It should definitely be done by the database if possible. Think about the scenario were two calls come into your API simultaneously on different threads. You won't be able to coordinate the assignment of the Id properly